# viewHolder.docimage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {} inside an RecyclerView adapter. onclick event is not happening.

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, searchview

I am using Recycler Adapter for search. in an Adapter I write viewHolder, By using ViewHolder I am performing on click action. But it is not happening. And I am also trying to inflate a view for showing Dialogue. It is showing null object reference.

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        LayoutInflater inflater2= parentAct.getLayoutInflater();
        View dialogView2 = inflater2.inflate(R.layout.customdialogue, null);
```

showing error. i change context to getApplicaitonContext and getActivity but it is not working.

Comment: Your context variable has a null reference. Paste your full `RecyclerView.Adapter`implementation here so that we can help you.

Comment: As for your first qualm, you are probably setting the `onClickListener` in the wrong function. Remember, `RecyclerView` recycles views. Again, we need your code to help you here.